# MySQL Query conditional OR

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I´m working with virtuemart, and I have a table that store all the information about the orders and the address of the users. When a user sign in they give me one address that I call 'BillTo' but when they make and order, the user can create a new address called 'shipto'. So If they create a new address 'shipto' I have to send the invoice to 'billto' and the items of the order to 'shipto'. I´m trying to get all the addresses to send the items of the orders. So I have the table like this

```
ORDER_ID   |   TYPE   |   ADDRESS
----------------------------------
1           BT           My office
1           ST           My house
2           BT           Home home home
3           BT            office
3           ST           office 2
```

I need to get all the ST addresses, and if not exists get the BT address.

```
1           ST           My house
2           BT           Home home home
3           ST           office 2
```

How can I do that?

EDIT:

This is my SQL query. 
SELECT `o`.`order_number`,`os`.`order_status_name`,`ou`.`first_name`,`ou`.`last_name`,`ou`.`last_name2`,`ou`.`phone_1`,`ou`.`phone_2`,`ou`.`address_1`,`ou`.`address_2`,`ou`.`zip`,`ou`.`city`,`uv`.`fieldtitle`

FROM `#__virtuemart_product_campaigns` AS `pc`

LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_order_items` AS `oi` ON (`pc`.`virtuemart_product_id` = `oi`.`virtuemart_product_id`)

LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_orders` AS `o` ON (`oi`.`virtuemart_order_id` = `o`.`virtuemart_order_id`)

LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_orderstates` AS `os` ON (`os`.`order_status_code` = `o`.`order_status`)

LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_order_userinfos` AS `ou` ON (`ou`.`virtuemart_order_id` = `o`.`virtuemart_order_id`)

LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_userfield_values` AS `uv` ON (`uv`.`fieldvalue` = `ou`.`provincia`)

WHERE (`o`.`order_status` = 'U' OR `o`.`order_status` = 'C' OR `o`.`order_status` = 'S') AND `pc`.`virtuemart_campaign_id` = '133' AND `ou`.`address_type` = 'ST' ORDER BY o.virtuemart_order_id ASC

Now, y remove from the query "AND `ou`.`address_type` = 'ST'" and delete the duplicates from the result with a foreach, but I would like to do it all in the same query

Comment: what are the attempts you made so far???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is if 'Type' is 'ST' include it OR if your table has a unique row (e.g for id 2 in your case) then also include it.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 
WHERE t1.TYPE='ST' OR
t1.ORDER_ID IN (select ORDER_ID from table1 group by ORDER_ID having  count(*)=1 )
```

Though it has nested query but will be easy to implement considering you don't have too much data.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to get your desired output by using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` over `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT ORDER_ID
,SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`TYPE` ORDER BY `TYPE` DESC),',',1) `TYPE` 
,SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`ADDRESS` ORDER BY `TYPE` DESC),',',1) `ADDRESS` 
FROM t
GROUP BY ORDER_ID
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7733df/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.*
from your_table t1
join
(
  select order_id, max(type) as type
  from your_table
  group by order_id
) t2 on t1.order_id = t2.order_id and t1.type = t2.type
```